# Shopify: How to display inventory quantities of a variant per location?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Is it possible to display the inventory quantity of a product variant in each location, on a product page? Since this information is stored in Shopify, and is available in the REST API, I expected that it would also be available as a Liquid template variable.

I see that [variant.inventory_quantity](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/variant/#variant.inventory_quantity) is available, but this seems to be the sum of quantities at all locations (although this is not described in the documentation).

What is the best way to display a breakdown of the quantities of a variant per location?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't find anything as simple as I had hoped. @Vladimir's answer was the best I found.

Comment: I created this app that uses the backend api to display it in the frontend: https://apps.shopify.com/product-inventory-information

I know some liquid is available now but it's still very limited

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is not available from within the Shopify templates.

I think the best solution would be creating a script triggered on `products/update` webhook to sync the information about inventory levels by location into the metafield.

Comment: I was thinking that as a last resort I could have a scheduled job that would put the inventory quantities into a metafield. Using a webhook would be much better than that, thanks! Still a shame that it's not just available in a Liquid variable though.